# windows 7 didn't do aaaa record lookup

Tags: windows-7, dns, ipv6

My laptop is installed with Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate , 64 bit version.

Recently, I went to the university, which only provides ipv6.

I've built a OpenVPN Tunnel to handle ipv4 traffic, but I've found when I enable OpenVPN Tunnel, all domain with ipv6 only will failed but numeric address (like 2001:a:b::c) works.

I've tried microsoft fix me 50441, which change settings to prefer ipv6 over ipv4, doesn't work. nor does changing the priority of ipv6 prefixpolicies(change ::ffff:0:0/96 to the lowest).

When I use wireshark to monitor my traffic, I've found that my laptop did only A record lookup instead of AAAA record. How could I fix it?

**EDIT:** I've added some information which may be useful for find out the problem.

```
C:\Users\Jack-YYF>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : LAPTOP-JACK
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter wlan1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 7E-E4-00-1E-71-2F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter tun1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-E6-D6-8B-5F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.6(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, February 22, 2013 23:00:20
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, February 22, 2014 23:00:19
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.5
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter tun0:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : gogo6 Virtual Multi-Tunnel Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-50-F2-00-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter eth0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C8-0A-A9-93-B3-54
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:da8:8001:3301:954d:8bd5:599c:97ba(Preferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2001:da8:8001:3301:1475:d65e:e534:d27a(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::954d:8bd5:599c:97ba%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.147.100.16(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::223:89ff:fe34:adb6%13
                                       10.147.100.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 398985897
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-D2-97-60-78-E4-00-1E-71-2F
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 2620:0:ccc::2
                                       2620:0:ccd::2
                                       202.120.224.6
                                       202.120.224.26
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter wlan0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 78-E4-00-1E-71-2F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8180:f992:bd60:2d75%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 293135360
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-D2-97-60-78-E4-00-1E-71-2F
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter btn0:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-27-13-D7-7F-EC
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: It's likely that IPv4 is Windows' preferred choice over IPv6.

Network and Sharing center -> Change adapter settings -> Advanced menu -> Advanced settings

At the bottom of this form move IPv6 above IPv4 and it should have the preference.

Comment: @Adambean Thanks for your comment. I have tried your solution, it works!

Comment: @Adambean Yes, you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Hi Mike, glad to here it worked out. I wasn't sure if it would work so I didn't post it as an answer. Have done now :)

Comment: Sorry, *Yifu Yu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that IPv4 is Windows' preferred choice over IPv6.

Network and Sharing center -> Change adapter settings -> Advanced menu -> Advanced settings

At the bottom of this form move IPv6 above IPv4 and it should have the preference.